# Android pulse LED notification while the screen is on

Tags: android

How can I make the LED or trackball pulse or flash while my application is running and the screen is on ? Like when a phonecall is received for instance ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Android has hard-coded functionality that LED gets on only while screen is off.
This is in source NotificationManagerService.java:

```
// lock on mNotificationList
private void updateLightsLocked(){
   ...    
   // Don't flash while we are in a call or screen is on
   if(mLedNotification == null || mInCall || mScreenOn){
      mNotificationLight.turnOff();
   }else{
      ...
   }
}
```

This is the function. Irrelevant parts are put to ... while actual behavior for this is in comment and in visible code.

We can't change this. But that's good to know for our debugging and testing of LED notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this class some time ago, but I was not able to make it work (even using different combinations of flags)  You could find [this post](http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/09/tutorial-how-to-use-led-with-android.html) useful.

```
public class NotificationUtils {
    public static void showStatusbarNotification(Context context, CharSequence text) {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
        notification.ledOnMS = 100;
        notification.ledOffMS = 100; 
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notification.flags = notification.flags |
            Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | 
            Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | 
            Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

        CharSequence contentTitle = context.getText(R.string.app_name);
        CharSequence contentText = text;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        nm.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that something similar than what I have now. But in only works when the screen is off.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look into this in the past and it seems that the android code is hard coded to switch off the led when the screen comes on for standard notifications raised by developers.

I'll try and find the code in android again where I saw this.